# Magmi import doesn't remove the products

Tags: magmi

I have been using Magmi to import products by adding items to the file " export_all_products.csv" without any problems
But when I have products that need to be remove,what I did was by removing the whole row in that product line in the csv file and upload it using magmi, but the products that I want to delete is still there and sometimes duplicated, is there a way to get it done or can I empty some tables in the database in phpmyadmin before I do the import?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Product Deleter](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Product_Deleter) plugin to delete products with Magmi.

Use the column name `magmi:delete` with the value of `1` on the rows you want removed from Magento.

Example CSV:

```
"sku","magmi:delete"
"00001","1"
"00004","1"
```